# Creating SQL compact database from Oracle database

Tags: oracle, sql-server-ce

We have Oracle database and need to create client with SQL compact, we will need synchronize data between them in future. How can we create SQL compact database from Oracle database(maybe somehow exporting schema etc.) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SQL Server Migration assistant to move to SQL Server, and then use Export2sqlce to create schema (or schema and data) - http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com

Comment: Just thought I'd add that I had issues with SSMA for Oracle (largely due to organization restrictions) but had great success simply created linked tables in Access to the Oracle tables and using SSMA for Access. Pulling the Oracle tables through those linked tables worked just fine (and surprisingly quick).